# renumber appended table row in javascript after deleting

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $('#mhTable').on('click', '.DeleteRow', function() 
    {
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        count --;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

hi i have these code to delete a table row, my problem is that when i delete a row that is in between the numbers, for example i have 4 rows and i delete row#2 the numbering of the rows will be like 1,3,4.. but i need it to be 1,2,3 how will i achieved this? thank you for your help

here's how i add the tables dynamically

```
var rowCount = $('#mhTable >tbody >tr').length;
var count = rowCount + 1;
var host = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + "\files/Icons/delete.png";
    $('#mhAddRow').click(function(e) 
    {
        $("#mhTable tr:last").after('<tr id="row' + count + '">'
        + '<td> <sup> <img class="DeleteRow" style="cursor:pointer;" id="rowDelete" name="rowDelete" height="7" width="7" src="'+host+'"> </sup> <input type="text" id="rowsID'+count+'" name="rows['+count+']" style="width:73%;text-align:center;" value="'+count+'" readOnly="readonly"> </input> </td>'

        + '<td> <input type="text" style="width:98%;" id="process" class="process" name="process['+count+']" value=""> </input> </td>'

        + '<td> <input type="text" style="width:96%;" id="PIC" class="PIC" name="PIC['+count+']" value="" > </input> </td> '

        + '<td> <input type="text" style="width:95%;text-align:right;" id="prev" class="prev" name="prev['+count+']" onkeyup="ManhourSaving();totalmhPrevious();ManhourSavingRatio();mhInMinutes();savedMHyearly();costAnnual()" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="5" value="" ></input> </td> '

        + '<td> <input type="text" style="width:95%;text-align:right;" id="expect" class="expect" name="expect['+count+']" class="expected" onkeyup="ManhourSaving();totalmhExpected();ManhourSavingRatio();mhInMinutes();savedMHyearly();costAnnual()" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="5" value="" > </input> </td> '

        + '<td> <input type="text" style="width:96%;text-align:right;" id="mhSavings" class="mhSavings" name="mhSavings['+count+']" readOnly="readonly" value="0.00" > </input> </td> '

        + '<td> <input  type="text" style="width:95%;text-align:right;" id="ratio" class="ratio" name="ratio['+count+']" readOnly="readonly" value="0.00" > </input> </td> '

        + '<td> <input type="text" style="width:95%;text-align:right;" id="PaperReducPrev" class="PaperReducPrev" name="PaperReducPrev['+count+']"onkeyup="PaperReductionPrevious();PaperReduction();PaperReductionRatio();totalPaperReduced();paperReductionyearly();costSheet()" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="5" value="" > </input> </td>'

        + '<td> <input type="text" style="width:95%;text-align:right;" id="PaperReducExpect" class="PaperReducExpect" name="PaperReducExpect['+count+']" onkeyup="PaperReductionExpected();PaperReduction();PaperReductionRatio();totalPaperReduced();paperReductionyearly();costSheet()" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="5" value="" > </input> </td>'

        + '<td> <input type="text" style="width:96%;text-align:right;" id="paperReduced" class="paperReduced" name="paperReduced['+count+']" readOnly="readonly" value="0"> </input> </td> '

        + '<td> <input type="text" style="width:95%;text-align:right;" id="PaperReducRatio" class="PaperReducRatio" name="paperReducRatio['+count+']" readOnly="readonly" value="0.00" > </input>  </td> ');

        $.post('mis.php/new_development_request/loadView_newDevelopmentRequest', {counter: count});
        count++;
    });
```

Comment: Numbered how and where? Show us your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the row first then update other tr using **$.each** function

Take a look at the fiddle to get your result: https://jsfiddle.net/hL625r4p/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        $(".row-id").each(function (i){
           $(this).text(i+1);
        }); 
    });     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td class='row-id'>1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='row-id'>2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='row-id'>3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='row-id'>4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sir i've updated my post, i've put the code on how i add table row. what if that is the approach i am doing? will your solution be possible?

Comment: yes. possible. Here is another fiddle as per your table structure: https://jsfiddle.net/eh57v847/

Comment: what i'm trying to achieve is that even the name of process, PIC, etc will be renumbered

Comment: Hi again sir.. what if i want to delete the row that i remove from the database. is it possible also? im sorry i really need some help regarding this.

Comment: @Dale, yes, possible. You can do that using jquery-ajax.