# Dynamically delete each row while append row index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dynamic, html-table

I'm kind of confused on how to dynamically delete each row while also updating all row index accordingly, instead of row 1,2,3, while deleting 2, the rows should be append into 1,2, not remained 1,3..

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('a.add-author').click(function(event){
        var number=document.getElementById("noofinputs").value;
        event.preventDefault();
        number++;

        var newRow = jQuery(
            '<tr>'+   
                '<td><textarea class="txtsize" name="item' +number + '" id="item' +number + '" rows="5" cols="32"></textarea></td>'+
                '<td><select name="category' +number + '" id="category' +number + '" style="width:202px;" >'+
                    <?php
                    $q3=mysqli_query($con,"select * from categories ORDER BY category ASC");
                    while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q3)){
                    ?>
                        '<option value="<?php echo $row3['no']; ?>"><?php echo $row3['category']; ?></option>'+
                    <?php
                    } 
                    ?>
                +'</select></td>'+
                '<td>$<input type="text" size="10" name="amount' +number + '" id="amount' +number + '" /></td>'+   
                '<td><a href="#" title="" class="remove-author'+number+'"><img style="cursor: pointer;" height="24px" width="24px;" src="http://../images/Cancel.png" /></a>    </td>'+
            '</tr>');

        jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
        $('#noofinputs').val(number);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".remove-author").click(function () {
     removeRow(this);
});
});

function removeRow(elem){
var i = 0;
var ii = 0;
var iii = 0;
$(elem).closest('tr').remove();
$("table.authors-list tr").not(':first').each(function (){
    $('td', this).not(':last').each(function() {
    $(this).find('textarea').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('name', 'item' + ( i+1 ));
        i++;
    });
     $(this).find('select').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('name', 'category' + ( ii+1 ));
        ii++;
     });
     $(this).find('input').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('name', 'amount' + ( iii+1 ));
        iii++;
     });
    });
});
var a=document.getElementById("noofinputs").value;
var b = (a - 1);
$('#noofinputs').val(b);    
}
```

I edited the code yet I can't even delete a single row...
I tried to follow this [renumber appended table row in javascript after deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281053/renumber-appended-table-row-in-javascript-after-deleting)
but it's not working at all...

EDITED: FINALLY it can be deleted and renumber its "number" name attribute after some changes!

Comment: this is because you have multiple `remove-author` classes on same page, that's why it deletes the last record matching to this class, you need to use a unique class or id for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Looks like you need to remove the `number` from `<a href="#" title="" class="remove-author'+number+'">`. Just leave it as `<a href="#" title="" class="remove-author">`.

You also you want to remove the `$('.remove-author').each(function(){`

jQuery doesn't act on elements that are created dynamically. So you'll want to create a new function and inject it into the `<a>` element (not the best solution, but it will work without heavily modifying your code)

So your code should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".remove-author").click(function () {
         removeRow(this);
    });
});

function removeRow(elem){
    $(elem).closest('tr').remove();

    $("table.authors-list tr").each(function (i){
        var txt = $(this).find('textarea').attr('name');
        $(this).find('textarea').attr('name', txt.replace(/\d+/, i+1)); 
        var sel = $(this).find('select').attr('name');
        $(this).find('select').attr('name', sel.replace(/\d+/, i+1)); 
        var amt = $(this).find('input').attr('name');
        $(this).find('input').attr('name', amt.replace(/\d+/, i+1));
    });
}
```

now you will want to add this to the `<a>` element

```
<a href="#" title="" class="remove-author" click="removeRow(this);">
```

Comment: Hi, on my page, I will load some data from the database on those table, and there will be number of rows are already there, the delete button can delete those rows except the newly created row by using add button..

Comment: The remove <a> tag needs the class of your jQuery .click function. So it should be `remove-author` and that is it. The class doesn't need to be unique because your code that calls $('.remove-author').click() will work. But I noticed that you have a .each() wrapped around that, probably want to remove that and just have a .click()

Comment: It can delete the rows that are already there, but if I add row, and try to delete that row, it doesn't work..

Comment: after removing the `'+number+'` from the `<a>` element's class?

Comment: yea, still doesn't work.. Is it due to index row of the newly created row??

Comment: Ok, looks like jQuery won't act on dynamically created elements like that. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Great! it works! But it seems the index, "number" doesn't append after delete, var name = $(elem).find('input').attr('name');
            $(elem).find('input').attr('name', name.replace(/\d+/, i+1));, this only return me undefined..

Comment: I have another table on that page, it might be better to define  $("tr").each(function (i){ which table for this tr?

Comment: Yeah you will want to contain that to just the table you are working with. You'll want to use `.find('textarea')` to find the textarea, and `.find('select')` for the drop down list.

Comment: I edited the code as shown above. It will still be 1,3,etc than renumber it as sequence number of rows. $(elem).find('td').each(function() { does this mean it will search each td in elem row?

Comment: I just realized that too. within the `.each()` loop, you should use `this` and not `elem`. Sorry about that.

Comment: still not working haha.. /\d+/ what's this?? It seems it search the input "name" value but it doesn't update the number behind it..

Comment: var txt = $(this).find('textarea').attr('name'); alert(txt); I used alert to see what's the results, turn out it doesn't find the specific textarea, it's just looping the whole td..

Comment: You don't need to loop each `td`, just do the loop for the `tr` and then within that be sure you are using `this` and not `elem`. I'm not exactly sure what `/\d+/` is doing, that was just copied from your code :)

Comment: after some changes, I can loop those attrb that I wanna change the number to be sequence, I just have to figure out this part $(this).find('textarea').attr('name', name.replace(/\d+/, i+1)); It still doesn't change the number.. But thanks for your help!! :D